# How to implement template logic in PHP

Tags: php, templates, logic

Having my first attempt with PHP templates and i'm a bit confused separating business with presentation logic.  I've choosen Dwoo as my template engine as you will see on the example below but my question is independent of Dwoo.
I see that what im doing isn't a good logic, it'll confuse the designer and it doesn't really separates PHP/HTML. I can't think any other way of doing it so please if anyone have the time explain me a bit.

Cheers.

PHP Code

$trans = translation('LABEL');

// Load Template Engine
$dwoo = new Dwoo();
   $dwooTpl = new Dwoo_Template_File('tpl/label.tpl.html');
   $dwooData = new Dwoo_Data();
   $dwooData->assign('title','Page Title');
`if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])){`
    `$dwooData->assign('logged',0);`
    `$dwoo->output($dwooTpl,$dwooData);`
`}else{`
    $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
    if (!isset($_POST['add'])){
        $sql = "SELECT labelName
                FROM label
                WHERE userID = $userID";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die('Can\'t get label'. mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($rs)){
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
                $labels[] =  $row->labelName;
            }
            $dwooData->assign('labels',$labels);
        }

```
    $dwooData->assign('logged',1);
    $dwooData->assign('addLabel',0);
    $dwoo->output($dwooTpl,$dwooData);

}else{

    $labelName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['labelName']);
    $labelName = trim($labelName);
        if(strlen($labelName) < 1)
        {
            $dwooData->assign('ERR1','Label Name is not valid.
                  You must enter at least 1 letter as Label name.');
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT labelName
                    FROM label
                    WHERE userID = '$userID'
                    AND labelName = '$labelName'";
            $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die('Can\'t get label '. mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs)){
               $dwooData->assign('ERR2',"Label '<strong>$labelName</strong>' already exists.");

            }else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO label
                        VALUES('','$userID','$labelName')";
                mysql_query($sql) or die('Can\'t insert Label '. mysql_error());
                $dwooData->assign('INFO','Label added Succesfully.');
             }
        }


$dwooData->assign('logged',1);
$dwooData->assign('addLabel',1);
$dwoo->output($dwooTpl,$dwooData);

}
```

}

Template Code

{include(file='header.tpl.html')}


    {if $logged == 1}
    {if $addLabel == 1}
        {if $ERR1}
            {$ERR1}
        {else}
            {if $ERR2}
                {$ERR2}
            {else}
                {$INFO}
            {/if}
         {/if}
    {else}
        Add Label:
        `<form method="POST" action="label.php">`
        `Name: <input type="text" name="labelName"><br>`
        `<input type="submit" value="add" name="addLabel">`
        `</form>`
        {foreach $labels label}
            {escape($label)}
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
{else}
     You must login to access this page.
{/if}
{include(file='footer.tpl.html')}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, turn it into three distinct template files:

- a single $ERRMSG template
- one "You must login.." page
- and a form

The application logic should define which of the three cases gets displayed.

Comment: Got the job done using your method thank you. Adding more and more templates will be hard for the designer to maintain, is that the only way this can be done, is that the logic behind "templates"?

Comment: No, it's a constant act of balancing. Splitting up templates is one way to avoid logic. But obviously you'll end up with a hundred files in the end. I based my decision in this case on the assumption that all three parts might accomodate wildly different layouts/styles. It also depends on the template scheme which method is more optional. For heredoc templates I'd use for example `{$include($err ? "error.tpl" : "ok.tpl")}`. But there is really never an optimal solution for alternatives/template parts.